# In Java,how can the letters in strings be doubled?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner no matter how you look at it, so bear with me here. The project is about having a string in the code and then doubling every letter in it, while tripling the exclamation points. Nothing else is doubled. It's supposed to take something like this:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 3 times!

...and turn it into this:

> Tthhee qquuiicckk bbrroowwnn ffooxx jjuummppss oovveerr tthhee llaazzyy ddoogg 3 ttiimmeess!!!

This is the code I tried, though it prints in numbers and takes a bunch of loops to complete instead of one:

```
String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 3 times!";
String output = "";
int i = 0;
while (i < s.length()) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (s.charAt(i) == '!') {
        output += c + c + c;
        i++;
    }
    if (Character.isLetter(c) == true) {
        output += c + c;
        i++;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: You really should use a string builder, but `char + char` produces a `char` not string. You probably want `output += "" + c + c + c;`

Comment: Also note all your cases increment i. So it would be clearer with a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use a `StringBuilder`, but `char + char` produces a `char` not a `String` (it does numeric addition). You probably want `output += "" + c + c + c;` since it will convert the `char`s to a `String` and then append them. (Likewise for the line `output += c + c;`)

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution could look like this:

```
String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 3 times!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c == '!') {
        sb.append(c).append(c).append(c);
    } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        sb.append(c).append(c);
    } else {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
String output = sb.toString();
System.out.println(output);
```

The problems it fixes

- Your code will skip a character after it encounters a `'!'`. You go into the first `if`, increment `i` correct, but then return to the rest of the code below, hit the next `if`, condition is false because `!` is not a letter, so it goes in to `else` path and increments `i` a second time. You should ether use `continue` to prevent fall-through or use `if .. else if .. else` which enforces mutually exclusive flow as well.
- A `while` loop is IMO more complicated to read than a `for` loop. You also don't have to increment `i` like 3 times. Once at the end of the `while` loop would be enough.
- String concatenation in loops is best done with a `StringBuilder`. It can also append `char` without converting it to a number.
- You forgot that you have to append `c` once when it's no special case.
- You don't want to do `System.out.println(output);` inside the loop but afterwards. That's why you saw a lot more output lines than expected
- formatting hiding issues like the one above

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 3 times!";

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char temp = s.charAt(i);

        builder.append(temp);

        if (Character.isLetter(temp)) {
            builder.append(temp);
        } else if (temp == '!') {
            builder.append(temp).append(temp);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the numbers back in characters first through a so called cast

like (char) output.

Try it and play around with it, learning and experimenting is the best thing about a beginning ;-)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `StringBuilder` gives a short and clear solution :

```
String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 3 times!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0 ; i<s.length() ; i++) {
    String ch = s.charAt(i) + "";
    sb.append(ch.matches("\\s") ? ch : ch + ch);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Character is a number that represents the actual english character. Adding two characters will give you just a new number that number will represent some new character** .

Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine for me...

```
    String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 3 times!";
    String output = "";
    int n = s.length();
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        String sub = s.substring(i, i+1);
        output = output + sub + sub;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the string what I think you are doing is printing the numbers asoociated with each character added together.

Add a `""` into your concatenation, i.e. `output+= "" + c + c;`

But make sure to add the empty string before you add the characters otherwise it will add the characters together, giving you a number, and then converting it to a string.

Also, in your else statement you might want to add an `output+= c` line, otherwise it looks like you will lose your number 3 and your spaces.